# Co-Dependent .h files with forward declaration

Tags: c++, header-files, forward-declaration

I have 3 classes (A, B & C) in different .h files. How can I move the `#include`s and forward declarations in order for it to compile.

Currently I've used forward declaration in A.h and thought it would work from there. Instead C.h is throwing many compiler errors of `'class A' is inaccessible with in this context`.

```
// A.h
#pragma once

...

class B;

class A {
  private:
    B *parent_;
};
```

```
// B.h
#pragma once

...

#include <A.h>

class B : A {
  public:
    virtual void func(A *arg);
};
```

```
// C.h
#pragma once

...

#include <A.h>
#include <B.h>

class C : B {
  public:
    virtual void func(A *arg);

  private:
    A *left_child;
    A *right_child;
};
```

Comment: Each header contains `#pragma once`

Comment: `class B; class A { B parent_; };` This won't compile. [You cannot define a non-static member variable of incomplete type.](http://eel.is/c++draft/class#mem-15.sentence-1)

Comment: You seem to want to create something like a tree. For that to work, `parent_`, `left_child` and `right_child` need to be pointers

Comment: Oh I forgot to specify. Just about everything is a pointer

Comment: Post your actual code please. Including the `;` after the class definitions --> [mre].

Comment: *"'class A' is inaccessible with in this context"* It is probably due to **private** inheritance.

Comment: You need to use public inheritance rather than private

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *name* `A` is private via `B`. You can either change to public or protected inheritance in `B`, or use (the fully-qualified name) `::A` in `C`

Comment: Ouch. I usually sit in the comfort of managed languages. I guess I need to go rework my structure to work in C++. Thank you

Comment: A lot of things already were, I just forgot to specify. I've updated the question

Comment: I'm sorry, idk what you mean by ``::A``. My C++ experience is limited

Comment: `::` is the scope resolution operator. It specifies "A from the top-level namespace", like `std::vector` is "vector from namespace std"

Comment: Got it, thank you! I didn't realize there's a global namespace, cool.

Comment: This problem is nothing to do with managed or unmanaged languages.

Comment: @user253751 the question (and this answer) drastically changed since that comment